# Protractor-cucumber: chai.expect does not work

Tags: protractor, chai

In Steps definition, i declare 'chai' and use to debug:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.usexpece(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;

module.exports = function() {

   this.Given(/^I go on "([^"]*)"$/, function (arg1, callback) {
   browser.driver.get(arg1);
   browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10000);

   var answer = 43;
   expect(answer).to.equal(42);
   console.log("this text will be displayed");

   callback();
});
```

}

When i run the script, text `this text will be displayed` does not appear ,in console but when i comment this line `//expect(answer).to.equal(42);`, the text appear as normal.

I know there is a wrong in `expect` of `chai` object but cannot find out the solution. Anyone can help me to resolve the issue. Thank so much

Comment: Which version of cucumber are you using? I tried your code with `0.7.0` version of cucumber and it worked as expected.

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar: Thank for response, i'm using cucumber v2.1.0, protractor 2.5.1, chai 3.4.0

Comment: where did you find v2.1.0 version of cucumber. Cucumber has released latest 0.8.1. Check here https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber

Comment: sorry my mistake, my cucumber version is 0.8.1

Comment: yeah it seems some issue with 0.8.1, you can try using that with 0.7.0. It works well.

Comment: I have alos raised a bug in cucumber which is almost similar to your issue. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/447

Comment: I just delete folder cucumer in "...\npm\node_modules" and run reinstall cucumber command as `$ npm install -g cucumber@0.7.0` but this issue still happen. Could you see full code project in here: [Project cannot run with Except](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429940/protractor-cucumber-project-cannot-run). Am i wrong on any config?

Comment: ahh silly mistake seems there, you are asserting 42 instead of 43. it should be `expect(answer).to.equal(43);`

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar: Thank you so much, it can pass the `expect` now.

Comment: The reason i writen `expect(answer).to.equal(42);` because i want to get fail result. What happen if condition does not equal as expected?

Answer (score 0):

cucumber-js supports steps that return promises.
When using chai-as-promised, i need to return the expectation (which is a promise)

```
this.When(/^I test async code$/,function() {
return expect(true).to.be.true;
});
```